# alphabetic scrollview in android

Tags: android

Is there any default function available for alphabetic scrollview in android or we want to implement manually, how can we implement.....
Is any other option available in android similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean sorting alphabetically try kind of this:

```
private final List<ContactDigest> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactDigest>();

public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
  .....
 List<ContactDigest> cs = app.getContacts();
 Collections.sort(cs, new ContactComparator());

 contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, R.layout.row_contact,
            contacts);

 ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts);
 list.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
  ....
}


public class ContactComparator implements Comparator<ContactDigest> {

    public int compare(ContactDigest c, ContactDigest c2) {
        return c.getUsername().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getUsername());
    }
}
```

....

Bye